# Get the raw video and audio dump from a SWF video

Tags: video, audio, flash, extract

I have a SWF movie (only animation, no Actionscript) and I would like to programatically extract the resulting video and audio and whatever resolution.

What method would be the best way of going about this. Any language, any technique is accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `gnash` to dump each frame to a file and then running gnash again to dump all audio to a file worked for my purpose. Check the man pages for more details.

However, it won't work very everyone because gnash doesn't work very well on windows and doesn't handle newer flash stuff very well.

Comment: How to dump using gnash? gnash --screenshot=all file.swf is not working. Just open the file and close immediately. --screenshot-file didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [SWFTools](http://wiki.swftools.org/index.php/Main_Page#General_information_about_SWFTools).  It has the building blocks that should let you complete such a task, although I've not done it myself.  [swfrender](http://wiki.swftools.org/index.php/Swfrender) and [swfextract](http://wiki.swftools.org/index.php/Swfextract) specifically should be of interest.  I could see it working like this:

1. extract rendered frames with swfrender
2. combine frames into a video with FFmpeg
3. extract audio with swfextract
4. mux audio and video into a single result

Comment: swfrender seems to only render the first frame...the python api seems promising though.

Comment: Hi Stu - I know this was a while ago. Any chance you have an example lying around anywhere for this solution?

Comment: if anyone figures out how to achieve this, it'd be quite useful to edit this answer or submit as a comment — the swftools wiki is out of date and doesn't match the commands anymore ):